# i keep failing load svg with webpack build product

Tags: typescript, svg, webpack

I'm making my own library with Google Maps

- src/component/index.ts

```
import icon_marker from './images/icon_marker.svg'

new google.maps.Marker({position, icon: icon_marker})

const test = document.createElement('img').src = icon_marker
```

@@@ these two don't work !!!

- webpack.config.js

```js
module: {
      rules: [{
              test: /\.svg/, 
              type: 'asset'
            }] 
        }
```

I've tried type: 'asset/resource', 'asset/inline', 'asset/source', and before these, many kinds of loaders.

i found image files created in dist folder but none of them is applied.

please help me, i'm so frustrated...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should use this syntax if using webpack5:
[image: webpack5 image asset]

If you are using webpack5 , please follow these rules https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images

Comment: i've made it work changing "import from" into "const require" thanks for answering